# Is there a security concern in RxJS library?

Tags: angular, security, rxjs, postmessage, penetration-testing

Currently I am working on a project that uses RxJS within Angular framework. A recent penetration testing report highlighted that the use of `window.postMessage(‘’, ‘*’)` in the application could lead to security vulnerabilities. Investigating this further, we found that Immediate.js file within RxJS (http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/util/Immediate.js.html) could be the source of this issue. The penetration test report states “If the postMessage() is used to transmit sensitive information between windows, then an unauthorised window would be able to retrieve this information as well”. There were suggestions to use an explicit target window instead of the wildcard('*') character in the window.postMessage() function to overcome this issue. Since this code is embedded in the RxJS library, we don't feel comfortable in changing it as it may introduce some undesirable effects.

Given the above scenario, I would like to know:

1. What measures can be taken to prevent other windows on the client machine listening to this Angular application?
2. Is this a known issue on RxJS and is there a fix available for this?

**N.B.** The penetration test was conducted by a third party and we don’t know the tools they may have used.

Comment: Are you using rxjs 5.x? `ImmediateDefinition` where `postMessage` is used only seems to be in rxjs 5 code and not in rxjs 6.

Comment: Did they pen-test the sources or the build application..?

Comment: I just checked the version and it is 5.5.2. I think it is time for an update to a recent version. I looked at the GitHub repository and seems this is removed in rxjs 6. @fridoo thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @MikeOne They only have access to our compiled application so I assume it is that they pen-tested.

Comment: If the Update to Angular > 6 fixes your warning it might be good for further users of you answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: @JonathanStellwag I will do that after I update Angular and test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating Angular from 5.5.2 to version 6 seems to have fixed the issue. During the update, rxjs was updated to version 6 as recommended by the [Angular update site](https://update.angular.io/#5.2:6.0l3). We followed the steps as provided by this site and now we are running rxjs 6, which does not include window.postMessage("", "*") function that was highlighted in our pentest.

@fridoo thanks again for pointing us in the right direction!